# Maximum frequency present in an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, fft, frequency

I guess there are various forms of this question peresnt here in stackoverflow. But I was unable to understand how I can solve my problem.

I have an image and I want to find the frequency content of the image.

```
img = imread('test.tif');
img = rgb2gray(img);
[N M] = size(img);
%% Compute power spectrum
imgf = fftshift(fft2(img));
imgfp = (abs(imgf)/(N*M)).^2;
```

I know I have to use the fft for this purpose. But I was wondering if I can find the maximum frequency in the images in terms of a particular value, say 'x cycles/mm' or 'x cycles/inch'.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you take a look at `imgfp`, you will notice that almost all images will have non-zero frequency content up to fs/2 (where fs is the sampling rate).  So you would need to clarify what you mean by "maximum frequency".

Answer (score 4):

The FFT returns data in an array, where each array element is somewhat related to cycles per total data width (or height, etc.).  So you could divide each FFT bin number by the image size in some dimensional unit (say "inches") to get cycles per unit dimension (say cycles per inch).

Note that except for some very specific narrowly specified types of images (say, constant amplitude exactly aperture periodic sinusoidal gradients), any image content will get spattered across the entire frequency spectrum and range of the FFT result.  So you will likely have to set some non-zero threshold for frequency content before you can limit your "maximum" frequency finding.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I guess I should start off by finding the bin number for the FFT.

Comment: Not "the bin number".  An FFT has N/2 bins (independent, for typical real input), each with a complex magnitude value.

Comment: Thanks for you guys, anyone can provide an example with python and scipy? I think this will help a lot!